# How to add to a cumulative String:

Tags: java

In one of my labs, I had to produce all the Pythagorean triples until a specific max. I found out how to get them but not how to add each of them to a specific string.
How do I change the code so the output look like this?

```
3 4 5
5 12 13
7 24 25
8 15 17
9 40 41
11 60 61
12 35 37
13 84 85
```

Code:

```
private int greatestCommonFactor(int a, int b, int c)
{
    int max = number;

    for (a = 1; a <= max; a++) 
    {
        for (b = a; b <= max; b++) 
        {
            for (c = 1; c <= max; c++) 
            {
                if (a * a + b * b == c * c) 
                {
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    return 1;
}


public String toString(){
    String output = ;
    return output+"\n";
}
```

Comment: the output should look like a grid...

Comment: Hi, as you have now answers now, you may think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to reward the one that gives you the most helpful comment.

Comment: I am new to this.sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not pass `a,b,c` to the method, they are just local variables, but you may pass the `max`. Then you don't need to iterate for `c`, just compute it from `a` and `b`

```
private static void greatestCommonFactor(int max) {
    for (int a = 1; a <= max; a++) {
        for (int b = a; b <= max; b++) {
            double c = Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b);
            if (c == Math.floor(c)) { 
                System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + (int) c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Call as `greatestCommonFactor(50);`

---

You can change the condition to `if (c == Math.floor(c) && c < max)` is you prefer